# Requisição feita ao Spring Boot esta retornando outra API de endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Montei um cenário de teste para tratar um erro que estava acontecendo no meu frontend.

**Situação Problema:**

O problema era que eu estava fazendo uma requisição para uma rota `‘/api/v1/telefones’`, o Spring acaba me retornando `‘/api/v1/perfis’`, como se o comportamento fosse um cache. Os dados no frontend, em alguns momentos não eram renderizados, e foi quando resolvi implementar o teste de stress já que não estava conseguindo pegar pelo modo debug.

Além de um ter pensado em ser um problema de cache, como uma rota que retorna uma API de Telefone, retorna uma API de Perfil, já que o endpoint está configurado com entidades pertinentes?

**Cenário de teste de stress**

Os testes realizados captou a seguinte quantidade de erros:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x8B6.png

O tempo e a quantidade de requests realizados estão armazenados na imagem abaixo:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMyfh.png

O cenário é uma massa de requisições realizadas em tempos alternados, para dois endpoins, o de perfil e o de telefone, simulando requisições paralelas. Veja o código Javascript que implementei para realizar os testes:

```js
setInterval(() => {

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(request.readyState === 4) {
    if(request.status === 200) { 
      // console.log(request.responseText);
    } else {
      console.log('An error occurred during your request: ' +  request.status + ' ' + request.statusText);
    } 
  }
}

request.open('Get', 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/perfis');
request.send();

} , 225);



setInterval(() => {

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(request.readyState === 4) {
    if(request.status === 200) { 


    if (request.response !== '{"data":[{"id":"9040de2b-137a-45d3-902e-5ecdf4cf8c6d","codigoDeArea":"22","numero":"123654789"},{"id":"c5490c98-6a3f-4bd7-a7bc-b282750cec97","codigoDeArea":"22","numero":"997855566"}],"errors":[]}') {
        console.log(request.responseText);  
    }
    } else {
      console.log('An error occurred during your request: ' +  request.status + ' ' + request.statusText);
    } 
  }
}

request.open('Get', 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/telefones/lista');
request.send();



} , 300);
```

O problema foi identificado quando a requisição estava sendo feita para a API de telefone. O código Java que implementa o *Endpoint* é bem simples esta construído na seguinte forma:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/telefones")
public class TelefoneController implements ControllerTemplate<TelefoneDto> {

    @Qualifier("telefoneServiceImpl")
    @Autowired
    private TelefoneService service;

    @Autowired
    private RestResponse<List<TelefoneDto>> responseList;

    (...)

    @GetMapping(path = "/lista")
    public ResponseEntity<RestResponse<List<TelefoneDto>>> buscaTudoPorUsusarioCorrente(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails) {
        String apelido = userDetails.getUsername();
        List<TelefoneDto> dtos = service.buscaTudoPorApelido(apelido);
        responseList.setData(dtos);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(responseList);
    }

}
```

O meu código do método de serviço é:

```java
@Override
    public List<TelefoneDto> buscaTudoPorApelido(String apelido) {
        List<TelefoneEntity> entities = repository.buscaTudoPorApelidoDoUsuario(apelido);
        return converter.toDtoList(entities);
    }
```

A minha query customizada é:

```java
@Query("select t from Telefone t join Perfil p on p.pessoa = t.pessoa join Pessoa pe on pe = p.pessoa join Usuario u on p.usuario = u where u.apelido = :apelido")
    List<TelefoneEntity> buscaTudoPorApelidoDoUsuario(@Param("apelido") String apelido);
```

Meu controle de Perfil é:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/perfis")
public class PerfilController implements ControllerTemplate<PerfilDto> {

    @Qualifier("perfilServiceImpl")
    @Autowired
    private PerfilService service;

    @Autowired
    private RestResponse<PerfilDto> response;

    @Autowired
    private RestResponse<List<PerfilDto>> responseList;

    @Autowired
    private PerfilValidator validator;

    @Override
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<RestResponse<List<PerfilDto>>> buscaTudo() {
        List<PerfilDto> entities = service.buscaTudo();
        responseList.setData(entities);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(responseList);
    }

    @Override
    @GetMapping(path = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<RestResponse<PerfilDto>> buscaPorId(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        PerfilDto entity = service.buscaPorId(id);
        response.setData(entity);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }

    @Override
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<RestResponse<PerfilDto>> salvar(@RequestBody PerfilDto perfilDto) {
        validator.naoPodeAdicionar(perfilDto);
        PerfilDto entity = service.salvar(perfilDto);
        response.setData(entity);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }

    @Override
    @PutMapping
    public ResponseEntity<RestResponse<PerfilDto>> atualizar(@RequestBody PerfilDto perfilDto) {
        validator.naoPodeAtualizar(perfilDto);
        PerfilDto entity = service.atualizar(perfilDto);
        response.setData(entity);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }

    @Override
    @DeleteMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> removePorId(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        validator.naoPodeRemover(id);
        service.removePorId(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(true);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/usuarioCorrente")
    public ResponseEntity<RestResponse<?>> buscaPorApelidoUsuarioCorrente(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails) {
        PerfilDto resp = service.buscaPorApelidoUsuario(userDetails.getUsername());
        response.setData(resp);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
}
```

**Bibliotecas e versões:**

- Java 8 (Fiz o Downgrade para o Java 8, antes era o 13, pois achei que talvez seria uma problema da versão)
- Spring 2.2.2.RELEASE
- Lombok
- JPA
- Postgre

**Como solucionar?**

1. Gostaria de saber como solucionar este problema?
2. Porque uma requisição que esta sendo feita para api de telefone, retorna uma um endpoint da api de perfil?

**OBS:**

NÃO ESTOU USANDO CACHE!

Link do vídeo com teste de stress:
https://player.vimeo.com/video/384000413

Link do projeto completo:
https://github.com/thiagosantoscunha/salesiana-start-backend

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que na consulta que você está fazendo, o relacionamento pode estar trazendo tudo, e o fato de trazer de /telefone a resposta de /perfil é o SQL.

Comment: Essa parte eu peguei no modo Debug, o jackson faz o reflection certo das entidades e realiza a consulta da forma correta. O problema ainda é maior!